# How do you assert that Django's QuerySet.count() method was called on a Mock?

Tags: python, django, mocking

I'm using Mock to replace a Django Model, and it is configured as follows:

```
>>> config = {'objects.filter.return_value.count.return_value': 1}
>>> MockModel = Mock(**config)
```

I can query for some values, and then call `.count()` on the result:

```
>>> # This works as expected
>>> MockModel.objects.filter(foo='bar').count()
1
```

However, when i assert that these methods were called, Mock raises a `TypeError` because
`count` is a method of Mock's `call`:

```
>>> MockModel.assert_has_calls([
        call.objects.filter(foo='bar'),
        call.objects.filter().count(),
    ])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-bf4e954d856f> in <module>()
      1 MockModel.assert_has_calls([
      2         call.objects.filter(foo='bar'),
----> 3         call.objects.filter().count()
      4 ])

TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Though, you can see that this call does exist in the `mock_calls`:

```
>>> MockModel.mock_calls
[
    call.trait_names(),
    call._getAttributeNames(),
    call.objects.filter(foo='bar'),
    call.objects.filter().count(),    # How do you test for this?

    ...
]
```

So my question is this: How do you assert that `count()` was called on a Mock Django QuerySet?

Comment: You could do this: `assert MockModel.objects.filter().count.called`, but this doesn't quite give you the correct information if the order of the calls matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `call` is also a `tuple` and so can be compared with a `tuple`:

```
>>> MockModel.assert_has_calls([
        call.objects.filter(foo='bar'),
        ('objects.filter().count',),
    ])
```

You can confirm this:

```
>>> map(tuple, MockModel.mock_calls)
  > [('objects.filter', (), {'foo': 'bar'}), ('objects.filter().count', (), {})]
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/mock/source/browse/mock.py#1988